# Is it possible to turn a color from dark to lighter with css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a div background color that turns from dark to lighter at the same time from top to bottom. Is it possible with css and javascript in html without using any background image?
This website uses something like this:
http://www.flvto.biz/
The middle orange section is what I want.

Comment: you mean a gradient? Is a gradient what you want?

Comment: Yes. It is. Anything else?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your answers and sorry for wasting your time :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look to css gradient property?
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: Thank You. This is what I'm looking for.